# Not able to Autowire Spring Bean in Spring AOP aspect

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have a new Aspect created and its not loading the autowired bean

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@Autowired
private EmployeeDAO  employeeDAO;

}
```

Autowired beans are not loaded and showing as null only.

spring version

```
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

Comment: How have you declared the beans? Code?

Comment: All the beans are declared through annoation.

Comment: @Component
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

Comment: Does your component-scan includes the packages where these annotations are?

Comment: Both the bean and Aspect are in same module and using the same context file to do component scan

Comment: //@Configuration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.test.example"})
//@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
//@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class SampleAppContext {
}

Comment: Try changing the annotation Component in the EmployeeDAOImp to this @Component ("EmployeeDAO")

Comment: Still I'm facing problem in getting that DAO as null. Is there POM dependency that I need to add??

Comment: That should be no problem, as long as you don't have any exception in the logs when you startup the server. It's a context problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71438/discussion-between-saysiva-and-luke-springwalker).